# Connect MySQL Workbench on PC to remote MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

MySQL Workbench operates on my PC at home with IP 1.2.3.4 and MariaDB is located on my server with IP 4.3.2.1.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/ describes editing `/etc/my.cnf`, but shows commenting out lines which do not exist in mine.

When I test my remote connection, I get error 10060 (denied).

How is this accomplished?

```
[root@greenbeantech etc]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[root@greenbeantech etc]#
```

Answer (score 1):

The error 10060 suggests that remote access to the machine isn’t allowed.

Verify that,

1) The machine has remote access to the MySQL server

2) In the my.ini/my.cnf file, comment the line that reads “bind-address” or set the bind-address to ‘0.0.0.0’. Also check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file and comment it and then restart the MySQL server for the change to take effect.

3) Also, ensure the MySQL user can be connect from any host. Use the ‘%’ wildcard for the host part of the MySQL user to which you are connecting ignorer to allow any host connect to it with correct credentials.